# MySQL server restart error when setting bind-address

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I am following this tutorial to setup a MySQL server on my Digital Ocean droplet, but using Ubuntu 16.04.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-to-a-new-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

When i set 'bind-address' as localhost or the public server's ip I can restart the server, but when I try to use private ip I get the an error.

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Throws:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status mysql.service

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-07-03 23:23:36 UTC; 10s ago
  Process: 16717 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16709 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16717 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 16718 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 332.0K
      CPU: 338ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─16718 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─16768 sleep 1

Jul 03 23:23:36 inradar-db-production systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jul 03 23:23:38 inradar-db-production systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

journalctl -xe (last lines)

```
Jul 03 23:24:37 inradar-db-production audit[16926]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/16926/status" pid=169
Jul 03 23:24:37 inradar-db-production audit[16926]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" 
Jul 03 23:24:37 inradar-db-production kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1499124277.901:460): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
Jul 03 23:24:37 inradar-db-production kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1499124277.901:461): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
Jul 03 23:24:37 inradar-db-production audit[16926]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/16926/status" pid=169
Jul 03 23:24:37 inradar-db-production kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1499124277.905:462): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
Jul 03 23:24:39 inradar-db-production systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
lines 2193-2214/2214 (END)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You must first check: See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. what details are there? Maybe some useful details of error

Comment: I have updated the description

Comment: Try to take a look here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1610765

Comment: I couldn't find a solution on that url. They look as lost as I am. Did you noticed any relevant advice?

Comment: I am not sure but that seem to be the solution: "GET_AROUND:
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
line 25 after:
# Allow config access
  /etc/mysql/** r,
-add line:
  /etc/mysql/* r,

systemctl restart apparmor.service

service mysql stop
service mysql start

- problem is gone"

Comment: So in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 25 after `Allow config access /etc/mysql/**  r` -add this line :  `/etc/mysql/* r` after that run in terminal `systemctl restart apparmor.service ` also restart mysql service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too. What exactly did you add to your my.cnf file?

On install, my my.cnf file was completely empty. When I added just the bind-address line I got the same error as you.

However when I add [mysqld] above it, it works... so try adding this:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

A bit of additional info: When I checked my journal I could see these error logs which seem to suggest that mysql is looking for something extra in the my.conf file:

```
Aug 03 13:22:03 ubuntu mysql-systemd-start[19667]: my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 23!
Aug 03 13:22:03 ubuntu mysql-systemd-start[19667]: my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

I can now connect to my db remotely.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Any reasoning behind why it didn't work with public ip but with 0.0.0.0?

Comment: This allows the connexions from any IP. Not an ideal solution...

Comment: The question was why is it failing when the bind address is added to the file. The answer is because you need to add [mysqld] above that line. You can set the bind address to whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

`sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-howto-disable-apparmor-commands/

Comment: Disabling apparmor completely is not a solution and dangerous

Comment: In case of using MySQL on a developer machine it is not the issue